# Points changing rapidly

Tags: android, collision-detection, andengine, collision, point

I like to make a game, but I get trouble with collecting points.
The purpose is to increase/decrease character point (charhop +1 or -1) whenever object 'face' is collided with injekBox, but the point just increase or decrease once then it return to the previous value.
The log also still print the value even if the object stop
I want to make the point change once if the 'face' collided with certain box, and will change again after collided with another box

```
char1.setHops(0);
public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if (char1.isJump()){
                int rockPoint = char1.getPoints();
                int maxBox = listBox.size();
                int charHop = char1.getHops();
                for (int j = 0; j < maxBox ; j++){
                    if (j == rockPoint){
                        j++;
                    }
                    Box injekBox = listBox.get(j);
                    if(injekBox.getRectangle().collidesWith(face)){
                        if(char1.isTurn()){
                            charHop++;
                            if (charHop == (maxBox - 1)){
                                char1.setTurn(false);
                            }
                        } else {
                            charHop--;
                        }
                        Log.i(this.toString(),"charHop: "+charHop);
                        injekBox.getRectangle().setColor(1, 0, 0);
                    } else {
                        injekBox.getRectangle().setColor(1, 1, 1);
                    }

                }

            }


        }
```

Sorry for bad writing...
Thank you for attention :)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `charHop` is only within `onUpdate`. Once you leave that method, the contents of that variable is gone. You need the counterpart to `char1.getHops()`--something like `char1.setHops(charHop);`.

Comment: Thank you mate. The points is change now, but it increase/decrease when 'face' is in touch with the box. Is there any way to make the point just increase/decrease once per touch?